# Meaning of (t[i, i+1]) for a term/variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

EDIT 2: corrected my equation, [i+1] and [i] are indexes of the waveform!

EDIT: sorry,  I thought it was a general enough question, but here's some background to my original question!

I want to solve this formula for the capacitance *C* at a sinusoidal voltage *U*(*t*) and the corresponding current *I*(*t*). In this case, *C* is dependent on the voltage *U*

$$I(t[i, i+1]) = C(U(t[i, i+1])) * \frac{dU}{dt}$$

I know that $\frac {dU}{dt}$ is the time derivative of *U*(*t*) and is calculated by $$\frac{U(t[i+1])-U(t[i])}{t[i+1]-t[i]}$$

My question is, when a parameter is written like this $I(t[i, i+1])$, does it mean $$I(t[i+1])-I(t[i])$$ ? It does look very similar to a  differentiation equation/linear recurrence equation but how do I solve to find the current?

Comment: Impossible to answer your question without the definition of $I$...

Comment: @LTJ_1212 Welcome to Math SE, I see that this is your first post. It's common sense here to post context and attempts along with the question =) So could you give more details about $I$ as Surb mentioned?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you, edited with some background!

Comment: $\dfrac{U(t+1)-U(t)}{t+1-t}$ is just $U(t+1)-U(t)$. This is not the same as $\dfrac{dU}{dt}$; it is just an approximation, which may be wildly out depending on how fast $U$ changes. Having said that, I have no idea what $I(t,t+1)$ means.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Current is not a function of two separate time variables.

Comment: $I(t,t+1)$ is certainly not a widely used notation for $I(t+1) - I(t)$. It is not even a common notation for anything at all, when $I$ is a function of a single variable. Where are you seeing this notation in use (that is, the actual book, or website, or other source)? Maybe your source introduces the notation somewhere earlier.

Comment: @JohnDouma I unfortunately do not have a source,I was given the equation and told to solve it using the differentiation method. I edited my post, since i have to use the differentiation method, I think it is meant to be I(t[i,i+1]), meaning all values of the current in between [i+1] and [i].

Comment: there is unfortunately no source @PaulSinclair, I'm thinking it's an error from my side and i, i+1 should be indexes of ONE variable. My equation might be related to linear recurrance equation, but I still have no clue how to solve for the current.

Comment: Someone gave you this equation. You need to ask *them* what the notation means.  If they have been teaching you, they should have explained the notation. You appear to be mixing up what is called "the calculus of finite differences" with what is normally called "calculus" (meaning the calculus of the continuum).